# Why is my C# application running on multi thread apartment?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

This is part of my Main method:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   #if !DEBUG
   try
   {
   #endif
   ApartmentState aps = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState();
   //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   MessageBox.Show(aps.ToString());
```

The message shows `MTA`. Any idea why or where should I start investigating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you just curious, or was it causing some other issue? Usually it's only a problem if you are trying to do some types of COM interaction in your main method. Windows will still run in the appropriate ApartmentState.

I haven't checked lately, but it used to be that regardless of the attribute, Visual Studio forced MTA. Did you try to run your application from outside of Visual Studio?

If it is only a problem in the debugger, uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" under the Debug section of your project's properties.

Comment: It is causing problems with an AxWebBrowser.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Now it runs on STA when on release mode. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Out of curiosity, was this a new project or converted from a previous version of Visual Studio?

Comment: .NET 4.0. I started this project on VS 2010 Express, then switched to Pro and now Ultimate since BizSpark gives it away :). Haven't found it much more useful so far though.

Answer (score 1):

This attribute sets the COM threading model for an application. If your application isn't using COM interop, it will have no effect.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx),

> COM threading models only pertain to applications that use COM
>   interop. Using this attribute in an application that does not use COM
>   interop has no effect.

Comment: Well, it has no useful effect in terms of the application - but the thread should still be in the apartment state you've specified.